# maven assembly plugin: descriptorRef not using basedir

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven assembly plugin to zip my web application dist folder.
I use this `descriptorRef` file:

```
<assembly>
    <id>webapp-build</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>dist</directory>
            <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

and I use it as a dependency in a parent pom like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>webapp-build</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptionRef>webapp-build</descriptionRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <basedir>${project.assembly.directory}</basedir>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Depending on the child using this parent pom, I would like to tell in which directory, the maven assembly plugin has to use the `webapp-build` assembly descriptor. I tried with `<basedir>` attribute but it is not using it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The [descriptorRef is intended](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptorRefs) to load assembly descriptors from [classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html) or using predefined descriptors. If you like to use the given descriptor you have to use `descriptors` instead like this:

```xml
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>assemblies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Furthermore a `basedir` configuration element does not exist for [maven-assembly-plugin:single](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html)

Comment: Exact, I forgot the dependency to load to use descriptorRef. Concerning the `basedir`, is there any workaround to use the assembly descriptor in different directories depending on the child project ?

Comment: Why would like to load it from different directories depending on if we are in child and load from dir 1 whereas in child b we use dir 2 ? The is a default location in the directory layout in maven...furthermore I'm not sure why you need different things for childs? Usually you make a separate dist module which contains the descriptor as well as the usage of maven-assembly-plugin ?

Comment: One child needs to use the build assembly descriptor to zip the `dist` folder which is at the root application level. The other child needs to use the build assembly descriptor to zip the `dist` folder which is in the `target` directory. To do so, I would like to set a `"working directory"` to be able to use the build assembly descriptor with a relative path either at the root application level either in the `target` directory. Is there a way to do so ? Otherwise I need two assembly descriptors depending on where the `dist` folder is...

Comment: Can you  make an example setup in Github or so to see what your really like cause I've got the impression your doing something wrong..

Comment: I hope it will help: https://github.com/louisamoros/mvn-angular-assembly

Answer (score 0):

`<basedir>` isn't a parameter of [`assembly:single`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html). There's [`descriptorSourceDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptorSourceDirectory):

> **descriptorSourceDirectory:**
>
> Directory to scan for descriptor files in. **NOTE:** This may not work correctly with assembly components.